# Elastic Beanstalk environment degrading due to high CPU utilisation

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cpu-usage

I'm trying to sync some google ads account into my system.

This process pull the data from the google ads account from 2017-01-01 to to last date.

Query for a single date, process it in a for loop to make a proper object

inserting into database.

Also tried with load balancers. But degrading occurs for one instance.

code

**querying google ads data**

```
var difference = dateDiffInDays(new Date(2017, 0, 1), new Date());

// getting last N days
days = LastNDays(difference + 1) 

// making array of date ranges
var result = days.chunk(20); 

// querying google ads data 
    for (var value of result) {
        const list = await customer.report({
            entity: 'keyword_view',
            attributes: adAttributes,
            segments: ['segments.date'],
            from_date: value[0],
            to_date: value[value.length - 1]
        })
        await saveKeywordsData(list, value[value.length - 1])
    }
```

I think the problem is the following function.

Becasue the output of above query is more than 5000 or 6000 (for a single date. Here calling date fro 2017-01-01).

So when handling more than 5000 data continuously for some time lead to high cpu utilisation.

**function saveKeywordsData**

```
async function saveKeywordsData(list, cronUntill) {
        let metricsArray = []
        for await (let element of list) {
            let metrics = element.metrics
            metrics.criterion_id = element.ad_group_criterion.criterion_id
            metrics.keyword = element.ad_group_criterion.keyword.text
            metrics.accId = accId
            metrics.agencyId = agencyId
            metrics.accountMId = accountMId
            metrics.date = element.segments.date
            metrics.dateTime = new Date(element.segments.date)
            metrics.createdAt = new Date()
            metricsArray.push(metrics);
        }

        // metricsArray length may be more than 5000 for each loop 
        await chunkInsertion(metricsArray, 'keywords')
        return 1;
    };
```

**function chunkInsertion**

```
    async function chunkInsertion(metricsArray, type) {
    let model
    if (type == 'ads')
        model = app.models.googleAdsInsights
    else
        model = app.models.googleAdsAuctionInsights
    var data = metricsArray.chunk(50);
    for (let item of data) {
        await model.create(item)
    }
    return 1
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you off load those heavy processing application to dedicated worker environment?

Comment: Let me check about this method. U means,  changing web server environment to workker environment?

Comment: You can keep web server environment for the website part of your app. Worker env would be used to process those long-running heave queries. This will require some  changes to your architecture as web and worker environments would need to interact. Maybe easier to just move to better instance and check first if this could help if you often run such heavy queries?

Comment: I think this for loop making this issue.

Comment: @Marcin Can you please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment.

I can provide only generic description on how a worker environment could be used. Exact implementation details are case specific.

[EB worker environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) are used for executing long running tasks. This could be a good solution for your use cases, as you would decouple your web environment from those heavy processing jobs that elevate your CPU.

In this scenario your web environment would be responsible for initiating the job and collecting the results.  It would not be performing the actual processing, which would be handled by the dedicated worker environment.

The worker environment exposes a SQS queue. This is different from a web environment which gives you url to your website. From worker env you get only the SQS queue endpoint. The endpoint is used to submit jobs to the worker. Your worker application would receive the jobs from the queue and perform the query independently from the web environment.

Handling of the results can be done in many ways. One way would be for worker  to write the results to, e.g. a DynamoDB. The web environment in that case would query the database for the result from time to time to check when they are available. The other way is for your web app to expose a dedicated url endpoint which would be called by the worker to signal the completion of a job.

This is how you generally decouple the web environment from long-running cpu or memory intensive tasks. But this would require changing how your application works and development of worker application to be deployed on EB worker environments.